# "Use for" vs. "Use as": what's the difference, and which is more appropriate when indicating a clear or perceived misuse?

Tags: prepositions

Consider the following:

> Our teacher used loaded firearms as teaching aids.

vs.

> Our teacher used loaded firearms for teaching aids.

Is there a BIG difference between the two? Does one of them imply certain context? Or just a more usual pattern? Which one sounds more natural?

Comment: Neither preposition implies judgment. Here, "as" means in the position of and "for," in the purpose of. You'd have to add *shockingly* or say the teacher apparently thought it was a good idea. In target practice, it might be.

Comment: Thank you Yosef. 
Does not "for" also bear a connotation of a "makeshift" something used "instead of the real thing"?

Comment: No. Depends on context. For now, I'll say this = Briefly, makeshift. For the purposes of our discussion = Specifically here. My kingdom for a horse = exchanged with one.

Comment: Yes, *for* could mean *instead of* or *in place of*. It depends on the context. *Our teacher used books for doorstops (because the school didn't have any doorstops).* Your sentence doesn't really work like that though.  *Our teacher used loaded firearms for [instead of] teaching aids (because...?).*

Comment: "for" is usually followed by an action, e.g. "for teaching how to shoot" or "for teaching riflery".

Comment: What difference do you really see, the more so if you replace 'loaded firearms' with '(anything)'?